# Woocommerce Hook after product insertion in backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've looked through Woocommerce API Docs to see if there's any way to manipulate the product after it gets inserted in the admin backend of Wordpress but couldn't find any. Maybe I missed it?

I need to pick product data and send it to an external API, and obviously, handle it on update and delete...

Is there any way/hook I can use?

Comment: Check out these action hooks: save_post http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post
before_delete_post
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/before_delete_post
delete_post
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes more into what I want. Taken from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110037/woocommerce-hook-publish-product) answer in WP forum. Thanks to the author

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse_110037_new_posts', 10, 3);
 function wpse_110037_new_posts($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
 if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'publish' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {
          //add some cde here
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If You add a new product in woocommerce then send product_id


add_action('draft_to_publish','my_product_update');


function my_product_update( $post ) {


    if($post->post_type == "product"){


         $pid=$post->ID;


         //your code

    }


}
```